# Build a custom WHERE expression for enum property and filter containing sub-strings

Tags: c#, filter, lambda, expression

I have a XAML datagrid where the columns represent the properties of some object, also have a enumerable of pairs IEnumerable<(string propertyName, string filterText)> filters, that represent the filter for some columns anf the applied filter text. This filter text is not necessary matching the value of the property. I want to generate a custom WHERE expression to filter the rows according to filter texts.

My code looks like:

```
        public static IQueryable<T> CustomWhere<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<(string, string)> filters)
        {
            if (filters.Count() == 0) return query;

            foreach ((string PropertyName, string FilterText) filter in filters)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = typeof(IStyle).GetProperty(filter.PropertyName);
                if (pi == null) continue;

                ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
                MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, filter.PropertyName);
                MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                ConstantExpression someValue = Expression.Constant(filter.FilterText, typeof(string));
                Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = null;
                IEnumerable<T> hh;
                switch (pi.PropertyType.Name)
                {
                    case nameof(IndustryTypes):
                        Expression containsExpression = ??? HOW TO GENERATE AN EXPRESSION THAT TAKES THE VALUE OF THE ENUM AND CHECK IF IT CONTAINS FILTERTEXT (SUBSTRING OF THE PROPERTY VALUE)
                        lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsExpression, parameter);

                        query = query.Where(lambda);
                        break;
                    case nameof(String):
                        MethodCallExpression stringContainsExpression = Expression.Call(property, method, someValue);
                        lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(stringContainsExpression, parameter);
                        query = query.Where(lambda);

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            return query;
        }
```

As can be seen, for properties of type string it is quite straightforwward, but how to do for properties of type e.g. Enum as IndustryTypes?
I also tried to convert the Enum expression to String Expression but not succesfull:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IndustryTypes), "enumValue");
UnaryExpression toString = Expression.Convert(param, typeof(string));
MethodCallExpression containsExpression = Expression.Call(toString, method, someValue);
```

There is a similar thread but it is matching the whole filter text using Expression.Equal:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801702/how-to-build-a-custom-expression-for-an-advanced-search-screen](https://stackoverflow.com) what is not my case.

Comment: This can't be both linq to sql and linq to entities - please fix your tags, and specify in your post exactly what EF you are using, and database provider. C# is a language of types - and `enum` can't be stored in a database, so it must be mapped to something, which might be the integer value and not the name, so you can't (easily) query on a contains of the name on the database side.